# date variable in hyperlink (metarefresh)

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to include a date variable in a URL based on todays date - specifically I am trying to include a link from sharepoint that will take a user to the relevant files in a shared drive.

My initial thoughts are an HTML page with a meta refresh that will take the user to the correct page:

I have been able to perform the below variables in VBA and autohotkey but I am new to Javascript so have not been able to create anything that works as yet.

This will need to be client based (hence javascript) - and the below is what i have, which is working but not dynamic

Could anyone please help by letting me know w. if JS is the best way forwards (i have access to notepad++ and no access to servers) and how i could include a date variable such as `YYYY` or month name similar the `Format(Date, "YYYY")` in VBA

```
<html>
    <head>
        <META http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=O:\Operations\Recc\Received\YYYY\Month Name">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>You are being directed to the correct location</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you meskobalazs
i now have the following but i think i am using it incorrectly
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var date = new Date();
var year = date.getFullYear();
var month = date.getMonth();
var monthName = getMonthName(date.getMonth());
function getMonthNames(month) {
var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];
  return monthNames[month];
  }
window.location.href = "file:///O:\Operations\Recc\Received\" + year + "\" + monthName;
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a `<meta>` tag, you should just use JavaScript:

```
var date = new Date();
var year = date.getFullYear();
var month = date.getMonth();
window.location.href = "file:///O:\Operations\Recc\Received\" + year + "\" + month;
```

I modified your original URL to use the `file` protocol, as file system URLs won't work otherwise in most browsers.

If you need the month textually, then you can write your own utility method with a lookup table, similar to this one:

```
function getMonthName(month) {
    var monthNames = ['Jan', 'Feb', ...];
    return monthNames[month];
}
```

And use it like:

```
var monthName = getMonthName(date.getMonth());
```

---

#### A complete example page

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <p>You are being redirected to the correct location...</p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function getMonthNames(month) {
        var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May",
                "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", 
                "November", "December" ];
        return monthNames[month]; 
    }

    function doRedirect() {
        var date = new Date();
        var year = date.getFullYear();
        var month = date.getMonth();
        var monthName = getMonthName(date.getMonth());
        window.location.href = "file:///O:\Operations\Recc\Received\\" 
                + year + "\\" + monthName;
    }

    setTimeout(doRedirect, 500);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This would work, however, as a security measure, most browsers disallow accessing the local file system, so what you want to achieve won't work in most browsers - at least by default.

Comment: Thank you meskobalazs i now have the following but i think i am using it incorrectly <html> <head> <script type="text/javascript"> var date = new Date(); var year = date.getFullYear(); var month = date.getMonth(); var monthName = getMonthName(date.getMonth()); function getMonthNames(month) { var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ]; return monthNames[month]; } window.location.href = "file:///O:\Operations\Recc\Received\" + year + "\" + monthName; </script> </head> <body> </body> </html>

Comment: could you advise if this should like in the body or the header tag? as it does not seem to be redirecting the page?

Comment: Added a complete example, the problem was with the escaping of the quotes.

Answer (score -2):

If i understood you correctly you should try adding this before  tag:

```
  <script>
  window.location = "mynewgeneratedlocation";
  </script>
```

This script will redirect page dynamically, but for adding custom data you should check out Date object

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp